# Eigenvalue of derivate of Poincáre map

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Let $p: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a periodical solution of the autonomous ode $\dot x = v(x)$, where $v:U \subset \mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a continous differentiable vectorfield. Further be $\Phi$ the flow induced by $v$ and $\omega >0$ the minimal period of $p$.

Here are my problems:

(1) The only eigenvalue $z$ of the derivation of the Poincáre-map at the fixed-point $\xi \in p(\mathbb{R})$ is positive. (I know why it has one.)

(2) $z = \exp(\int_0^w div \space v(\Phi(\xi, t))\space dt)$

Comment: What did you try?